# Detect if appointment is deleted with EWS

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I'm writing a .NET COre 2.2 application which can create appointments in Outlook, and on special conditions, it can delete them. For this, I use the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices 2.2.0 package, and I connect to an Exchenge Server 2016.

I store the ID of an appointment, and I use it to delete it. However, I don't want to delete it programatically, if the user has already deletet it in his Outlook:

```
ExchangeService service = ...;
var appointmentId = "asd123";

Appointment appointment = Appointment.Bind(service, appointmentId);
if (/*Verify that the appointment is not already deleted by the user*/)
{ 
    CancelMeetingMessage cancelMessage = appointment.CreateCancelMeetingMessage();
    cancelMessage.Body = new MessageBody("This plan was removed by our admin.");

    cancelMessage.SendAndSaveCopy();
}
```

I have tried a lot of things, but I can't find anything that can provide me with this information:

- `appointment.IsCancelled` is false in every case
- `appointment.DeletedOccurrences` is always null
- `appointment.AppointmentState` is always 1, no matter if it's accepted, cancelled, deleted or anything
- `appointment.ParentFolderId.FolderName` is always null, so I can't compary it with any WellKnownFolderName (like DeletedItems)

I deleted the appointment from my calendar with the Del button and with Right > Delete (like a normal user would do), but it made no difference.

Is there any way to detect if the user has deleted the appointment? Or any explanation why the above mentioned ways do not work?